# Buggy NSPopupButton in Cocoa MacOS Swift/Objective-C doesn't allow user to select first item

Tags: swift, cocoa, nspopupbutton

If we tried to create an `NSPopupButton` in swift/objective-c we find that if we don't set pullsdown to false, once an item other than the 1st item is selected you would never be able to select the first item back.

```
class PopupButton: NSPopUpButton {

    let items = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]

    override init(frame buttonFrame: NSRect, pullsDown flag: Bool) {
        super.init(frame: buttonFrame, pullsDown: flag)

        items.forEach { item in
            menu?.addItem(withTitle: item, action: #selector(handleSelectedItem(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
        }
    }

    @objc private func handleSelectedItem(_ selectedItem: NSMenuItem) {
        title = selectedItem.title
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Is there a way where I could fix this?
(Note: I don't want answers that say to set pullsDown to false and issue is fixed. I need to keep the behaviour of the PopupButton as expected.)

Comment: See [Pull-Down Buttons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/buttons/pull-down-buttons/). "If you need to provide a list of mutually exclusive choices that aren’t commands, use a pop-up button instead."

Answer (score 2):

From the [Documentation archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/ManagingPopUpItems.html), that is the way a pull-down button works.  It is more like a menu - the title isn’t based on the selection, the title only changes when you explicitly set it.  The list actually starts at index 1 - index 0 can be used for storing the title (although you should still set it), which is why the first item in your list isn’t being used in the menu.

Comment: If index starts at 1 when a developer adds an item it should add first item at 1 not at 0.

Comment: You would need to take that up with Apple, it works the way they wrote it.  I usually just set the first array item to the title, and add menu items from there.  If I need the title to change, I reset the title of the pull-down with the selection (or use a popup button).