# Why is a dummy NSMenuItem needed to make the next NSMenuItem actually appear?

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I want to programmatically populate an `NSMenuToolbarItem`'s `NSMenu`.

```
let toolbarItem = NSMenuToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: ...)
toolbarItem.image = ...
toolbarItem.label = ...
toolbarItem.menu.delegate = self
```

In my class that conforms to `NSMenuDelegate` protocol. I implemented the `menuNeedsUpdate(_:)` method:

```
func menuNeedsUpdate(_ menu: NSMenu) {
    menu.items.removeAll()
    menu.items = makeMenuItems()
}
```

In my `makeMenuItems()` method:

```
func makeMenuItems() -> [NSMenuItem] {
    [NSMenuItem(title: "Dogs", action: nil, keyEquivalent: ""),
     NSMenuItem(title: "Cats", action: nil, keyEquivalent: ""),
     NSMenuItem(title: "Foxes", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")]
}
```

When I run the app and check to see if there are three `NSMenuItem` that I expected. This is what I got:

[image: A screenshot of an NSMenu with two NSMenuItem items]

I found it strange that "Dogs" `NSMenuItem` is missing.

So what I did was insert a blank `NSMenuItem` to make the "Dogs" `NSMenuItem` appear. I refactored `makeMenuItems()` method like this:

```
func makeMenuItems() -> [NSMenuItem] {
    [NSMenuItem(),
     NSMenuItem(title: "Dogs", action: nil, keyEquivalent: ""),
     NSMenuItem(title: "Cats", action: nil, keyEquivalent: ""),
     NSMenuItem(title: "Foxes", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")]
}
```

I run the app again and it is what I expected:

[image: A screenshot of an NSMenu with three NSMenuItem items]

Is this a normal behaviour? If not, should I or somebody file a feedback to Apple? I can't find any documentation about the `.init()` initialiser. There are documentation for `init(title:action:keyEquivalent:)` and `init(coder:)` initialiser.

This was done on macOS Sonoma.

Comment: What are the items of the menu after creation?

Comment: Nothing. I just simply populate the `NSMenu`.

Comment: It looks like `NSMenuToolbarItem` is implemented with a `NSPopupButton` in pull-down mode. See [Buggy NSPopupButton in Cocoa MacOS Swift/Objective-C doesn't allow user to select first item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452465/buggy-nspopupbutton-in-cocoa-macos-swift-objective-c-doesnt-allow-user-to-selec).

Comment: Under what class are you doing all that?

Comment: `NSWindowController` subclass.